# String replacement using a dictionary

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, gawk

What is a good way to do string replacements in a file using a dictionary with *a lot* of substituend-substituent pairs? And by *a lot*, I actually mean about 20 – not much, but many enough so that I want to organize them neatly.

I kind of want to collect all substituend-substituent pairs in a file `dictionary.txt` in an easy-to-manage way, since I need to replace a lot of stuff, say like:

```
"yes"      : "no"
"stop"     : "go, go, go!"
"wee-ooo"  : "ooooh nooo!"
"gooodbye" : "hello"

"high"     : "low"
"why?"     : "i don't know"
```

Now I want to apply these substitutions in some file `novel.txt`.

Then I want to run `magiccommand --magicflags dictionary.txt novel.txt` so that all instances of `yes` in `novel.txt` are replaced by `no` (so even `Bayesian` would be replaced by `Banoian`) and all instances of `goodbye` in `novel.txt` would be replaced by `hello` and so forth.

So far, the strings I need to replace (and replace with) do *not* have any quotes (neither single nor double) in them. (It would be nice, though, to see a solution working well with strings containing quotes, of course.)

I know `sed` and `awk` / `gawk` can do such stuff principally, but can they also work with such dictionary files? Seems like `gawk` would be the right candidate for `magiccommand`, what are the right `magicflags`? How do I need to format my `dictionary.txt`?

Comment: Is perl acceptable? There's a nice trick for compiling up a set of search and replace patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed '
s|"\(.*\)"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"\(.*\)"|\1\
\2|
h
s|.*\n||
s|[\&/]|\\&|g
x
s|\n.*||
s|[[\.*^$/]|\\&|g
G
s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|s/\1/\2/g|
' dictionary.txt | sed -f - novel.txt
```

How it works:
The 1st `sed` turns `dictionary.txt` into a script-file (editing commands, one per line). This is piped to the 2nd `sed` (note the `-f -` which means read commands from `stdin`) that executes those commands, editing `novel.txt`.
This requires translating your format

```
"STRING"   :   "REPLACEMENT"
```

into a `sed` command and escaping any special characters in the process for both `LHS` and `RHS`:

```
s/ESCAPED_STRING/ESCAPED_REPLACEMENT/g
```

So the first substitution

```
s|"\(.*\)"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*"\(.*\)"|\1\
\2|
```

turns `"STRING"   :   "REPLACEMENT"` into `STRING\nREPLACEMENT` (`\n` is a newline char). The result is then copied over the `h`old space.
`s|.*\n||` deletes the first part keeping only `REPLACEMENT` then `s|[\&/]|\\&|g` escapes the reserved characters (this is the `RHS`).
It then e`x`changes the hold buffer with the pattern space and `s|\n.*||` deletes the second part keeping only `STRING` and `s|[[\.*^$/]|\\&|g` does the escaping (this is the `LHS`).
The content of the hold buffer is then appended to pattern space via `G` so now the pattern space content is `ESCAPED_STRING\nESCAPED_REPLACEMENT`.
The final substitution

```
s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|s/\1/\2/g|
```

transforms it into `s/ESCAPED_STRING/ESCAPED_REPLACEMENT/g`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl version.  It creates a hash containing pre-compiled regular expressions and then loops through each line of input applying all the regexes to each line.  `perl`'s `-i` is used for "in place editing" of the input file.  You can easily add or change any of the regexes or replacement strings.

Pre-compiling the regexes using `qr//` greatly improves the speed of the script, which will be very noticable if there are a lot of regexes and/or a lot of input lines to process.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl -i

use strict;

# the dictionary is embedded in the code itself.
# see 2nd version below for how to read dict in
# from a file.
my %regex = (
    qr/yes/      => 'no',
    qr/stop/     => 'go, go, go!',
    qr/wee-ooo/  => 'ooooh nooo!',
    qr/gooodbye/ => 'hello',
    qr/high/     => 'low',
    qr/why\?/    => 'i don\'t know',
);

while (<>) {
      foreach my $key (keys %regex) {
            s/$key/$regex{$key}/g;
      }
}
```

Here's another version which reads in the dictionary from the first filename on the command line, while still processing the second (and optional subsequent) filenames:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl -i

use strict;

# the dictionary is read from a file.
#
# file format is "searchpattern replacestring", with any
# number of whitespace characters (space or tab) separating
# the two fields.  You can add comments or comment out dictionary
# entries with a '#' character.
#
# NOTE: if you want to use any regex-special characters as a
# literal in either $searchpattern or $replacestring, you WILL
# need to escape them with `\`.  e.g. for a literal '?', use '\?'.
#
# this is very basic and could be improved.  a lot.

my %regex = ();

my $dictfile = shift ;
open(DICT,'<',$dictfile) || die "couldn't open $dictfile: $!\n";
while(<DICT>) {
    s/#.*// unless (m/\\#/); # remove comments, unless escaped.
                             # easily fooled if there is an escaped 
                             # '#' and a comment on the same line.

    s/^\s*|\s*$//g ;         # remove leading & trailing spaces
    next if (/^$/) ;         # skip empty lines

    my($search, $replace) = split;
    $regex{qr/$search/} = $replace;
};
close(DICT);


# now read in the input file(s) and modify them.
while (<>) {
      foreach my $key (keys %regex) {
            s/$key/$regex{$key}/g;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Started writing this as a comment, but it got too complicated, hence a second perl answer. Given your source file, you can use a neat perl trick to build a regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;

#build key-value pairs
my %replace = map { /"(.+)"\s*:\s*"(.+)"/ } <DATA>;
print Dumper \%replace; 

#take the keys of your hash, then build into capturing regex
my $search = join ( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %replace ); 
$search = qr/($search)/;

print "Using match regex of: $search\n";

#read stdin or files on command line, line by line
while ( <> ) { 
    #match regex repeatedly, replace with contents of hash. 
    s/$search/$replace{$1}/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
"yes"      : "no"
"stop"     : "go, go, go!"
"wee-ooo"  : "ooooh nooo!"
"gooodbye" : "hello"

"high"     : "low"
"why?"     : "i don't know"
```

We generate a hash using a multi-line pattern match and `map` to create key value pairs.

We build a search regex, and use the values captured in it to replace.

Using `<>` is perl's magic filehandle - `STDIN` or files specified on command line. Much how sed does it. (You can use a file and read it 'normally' for the pattern, the use of `DATA` is purely illustrative).