# Text processing : Replacing strings in a line with corresponding strings

Tags: text-processing, text

I have these as input files

**file1**

```
Red + Yellow = Orange; Yellow + Blue = Green; Blue + Red = Violet
```

**file2**

```
Red;1
Yellow;2
Blue;3
```

I am doing this in unix.

Output

**file3**

```
1 + 2 = Orange; 2 + 3 = Green; 3 + 1 = Violet
```

Comment: Are the `strings` all single words, space delimited?

Comment: strings are delimited by semicolon. file1 and file3 are single rows. file2 should looks like this:
Red;1 \n
Yellow;2 \n
Blue;3 \n

Comment: Possible duplicates: [String replacement using a dictionary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269368) or [Replace strings in a file based on a list of strings and a list of corresponding replacements](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271078)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR == FNR { # First file
    split($0,a,/;/)
    #print "change " a[1] "to " a[2]
    change[a[1]]=a[2]
}
NR != FNR {
    for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {
            if ($i in change) {
                    $i=change[$i]
            }
    }
    print
}' file2 file1
```

Use the awk idiom NR != FNR to tell if this is the first file or the second. If it is the first file then split the line on `;` and store the mapping in the change array. If it is the second then loop over the input field, if any match then replace with the correct change. At the end print the result.

Comment: Thank you for that. What if I change my file 2 into something like this?
Red;1 2
Yellow;2 3
Blue;3 1

And the output file will look like this 
1 2 + 2 3 = Orange; 2 3 + 3 1 = Green; 3 1 + 1 2 = Violet

which is essentially just replacing the strings in file1 with the corresponding string in the 2nd col of file2. Will this still work?

Comment: @peon please edit your question to show the data files, and try the commands. If I understand your comment correctly the answer is `yes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=";"
while read NAME VALUE
do
    sed -i "s/${NAME}/${VALUE}/g" file1
done < file2
```

Comment: This would also replace the words when they occur as substrings, as in `LightBlue`.