# Substitute text fields with values from other file

Tags: text-processing

Alright, I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have a `fileA` which looks like this :

```
([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"       
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -398015316.7
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0        

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"       
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : -374515458
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

and so on where the [index] goes from 0 to 71 and each station has a different ID.

I want to replace the value corresponding to `RIMSclockBias_A` string of each station with a value I have on another `fileB` like this:

```
CNR -44163754.49
ABS 3417370.112
...
```

So to have:

```
([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"       
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -44163754.49
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0        

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"       
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : 3417370.112
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

I can isolate the correct field with a combination of `grep` in a `for` loop and `awk`, but I don't know how I can replace the value in the file itself. `sed` needs to know the exact value I want to replace as input so it is not feasible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269368) only in this case the substitution has to be made on the first line that matches `clockBias` after the pattern. If there was no special character in your `fileB` you could run with `gnu sed` :

```
sed -E 's|(.*)[[:blank:]](.*)|/\1/,/clockBias/{/clockBias/{s/(:[[:blank:]]{1,})(.*)/\\1\2/}}|' fileB | sed -Ef - fileA
```

That simply turns the lines in your `fileB` into `sed` commands e.g.:

```
/CNR/,/clockBias/{/clockBias/{s/(:[[:blank:]]{1,})(.*)/\1-44163754.49/}}
```

and then passes them to the second `sed` to process `fileA`.

---

With unknown input you'd have to escape any special characters in the *LHS/RHS* as I've explained in my answer to the other question (this time using *BRE* syntax):

```
sed 's|\(.*\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\(.*\)|\1\
\2|
h
s|.*\n||
s|[\&/]|\\&|g
x
s|\n.*||
s|[[\.*^$/]|\\&|g
G
s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|/\1/,/clockBias/{/clockBias/{s/\\(:[[:blank:]]\\{1,\\}\\)\\(.*\\)/\\1\2/}}|' fileB | sed -f - fileA
```

Comment: What about if the pattern is not always on the 2 line after the match? Would be any smarter way to tell him to do the replace only in correspondence of ClockBias string?

Comment: Thanks don_crissti. By the way it is not working properly. Running your code it makes "strange" substitutions, e.g.:
ABS
(RIMSclockBias_A[0])                                    : 4536230.86    
->
(RIMSclockBias_A[0])                                    : -490697.2517

or for ALB
(RIMSclockBias_A[2])                                    : 11074942.05
->
(RIMSclockBias_A[2])                                    : -490697.2517

and so onwhile my fileB has:

ABS -44163754.49
ALB -37625043.3

I don't see where is the problem with your code.

Comment: @Dad85 - using _your input sample_  my code above works absolutely fine (try for yourself... I've even created a file 500 lines long with the same structure and with `clockBias` in random locations in every paragraph and it still works OK). I can only work with the input sample that you provide so I cannot know what's wrong on your side... (there could be a lot of things from hidden funky chars in your file to windows line endings or whatnot).