# How do I read a properties file through my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, sed, files

I'm using bash shell.  I'm trying to write a script that will read a properties file and then do some replacements in another file based on the key-value pairs it reads in the file.  So I have

```
#!/bin/bash

file = "/tmp/countries.properties"

while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
  echo "${key} ${value}" 
  sed -ie 's/:iso=>"${key}"/:iso=>"${key}",:alpha_iso=>"${value}"/g' /tmp/country.rb
done < "$file"
```

but when I go to run the file, I get a "Nno such file or directory error," despite the fact my file exists (I did an "ls" after to verify it).

```
localhost:myproject davea$ sh /tmp/script.sh 
=:                         cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
/tmp/countries.properties: ASCII text
/tmp/script.sh: line 9: : No such file or directory
localhost:myproject davea$ 
localhost:myproject davea$ ls /tmp/countries.properties 
/tmp/countries.properties
```

What else do I need to do to read in my properties file successfully?

Comment: If you use `while..read` to process text files [you're doing it wrong](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) (not only that but for each key=value you'll process the entire file with `sed` - so one thousand lines - one thousand `sed` invocations...) See the answers here: [String replacement using a dictionary](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269368) for proper ways to do it...

Comment: `file = "/tmp/countries.properties"` should be rewritten as `file="/tmp/countries.properties"` with no spaces around the `=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The errors are right there:

```
=:                         cannot open `=' (No such file or directory)
```

Something is trying to open a file called `=`, but it doesn't exist.

```
/tmp/script.sh: line 9: : No such file or directory
```

This would usually have the file name before the last colon, but since it's empty, it seems something is trying to open a file with an empty name.

Consider the line:

```
file = "/tmp/countries.properties"
```

That runs the command `file` with arguments `=` and `/tmp/countries.properties`. (The shell doesn't care what the arguments to a command are, there might be something that uses the equals sign as an argument.) Now, `file` just so happens to be [a program used for identifying the types of files](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file), and it does just that. First trying to open `=`, resulting in an error, and then opening `/tmp/countries.properties`, telling you what it is:

```
/tmp/countries.properties: ASCII text
```

The other `No such file or directory` comes from the redirection `< $file`. Since the variable isn't assigned a value, the redirection isn't going to work.

An assignment in shell requires that there be *no* white space around the `=` sign, so:

```
file=/tmp/countries.properties
```

---

Also, here:

```
sed -ie 's/:iso=>"${key}"/:iso=>"${key}",:alpha_iso=>"${value}"/g'
```

Variables aren't expanded within single quotes, and you have those around the whole second argument, so `sed` will get literal `${key}` and not the contents of the variable.

Either end the single-quotes to expand the variables, or just use double-quotes for the whole string:

```
sed -ie 's/:iso=>"'${key}'"/:iso=>"'${key}'",:alpha_iso=>"'${value}'"/g' 
sed -ie "s/:iso=>\"${key}\"/:iso=>\"${key}\",:alpha_iso=>\"${value}\"/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
file="/tmp/countries.properties"
```